# Get the path from code inside an AJAX callback

Tags: views, ajax, hooks

I need the current path (or URL) inside a view hook where I alter filters.
Precisely, I need the node ID, so I use the following code.

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
```

This works. The problem is that the hook (`hook_views_query_alter()`) is also invoked from an AJAX callback, so the code doesn't work.

So I'm trying the following code.

```
$current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
$path = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getPathByAlias($current_path);
```

This works, but on `$current_path` I get a string like `"//my/url"` instead of `"/my/url"`, so I should remove the first character from the value in `$current_path`.

Is there another way to get the node ID?

Using the debugger, I notice that the only variable containing the URL is `$_SERVER['REFERER']`, but I don't want to use it.

Comment: I take the view are trying to alter is showing a list of nodes, isn't it?

Comment: Also, the first snippet you show should not work for a view, since its path is not node/{node}.

Comment: On a node template I'm embedding a view that has an infinite scroll pager that works with ajax callback. In the hook I've to override the value of a filter, the new value must be the node I'm viewing

Comment: What does the embedded view show? What code are you using to embed the view?

Comment: The embedded view is a simple view with pager from module views_infinite_scroll. I'm using twig_tweaks module and in the template I've: drupal_view('autore', 'canti_autore_altri').

I've a content type "canto" that has 2 entityreference referred to "auhor" node. When I view an author node I've to see "canto" nodes that has a reference to the author in field1 OR field2.
And I can't use contextual filters in "or" condition.